# Algorithms running in ASP.NET IIS slower than in Console?

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

I have a search API that takes only 115ms when I run it in a Console App but the same code takes 450ms if I run it in an ASP.NET 4.8 web app. The algorithm uses 1 thread only. Both were built with AnyCPU setting. OS: Windows 10 64bit

I tried many ways and read many topics on SO to improve the performance of my web app but no lucks:

- Enable 32 bits (not possible)
- Remove unused modules
- Release mode

What could be the reason?

Comment: It is not clear if this is the same computer for both tests? And ANY CPU when launched from VS will result in the console application running as x32. So, for a better test, you would do well to force both projects to x64 bits for testing.

Comment: See my follow up edit in my post - I note to check the computer optimizing settings. Your reported reduction in performance is often seen in looping intensive code when the optimizations computer setting is turned off.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about the same computer and server for both tests? Or is one some hosted solution and the other is a console running local? I mean, apples and oranges compare. If you talking about the SAME computer (say running your console code), and then running the same code when launch from a local copy of IIS running, then one should not see a lot of difference.

But, if you tell me you borrowed a rope from the farmer next door? You WOULD THINK that you would ALSO include that a cow was attached to that rope? (don't you think?). So often cloud hosted solutions and especially Azure (or Amazon) web services systems?

Well, they have CPU usage governors left right and center (they throttle the CPU usage so that one heavy process does not effect everyone else. As a result, the processing ratings you get tend to be REALLY bad (poor CPU). They are often down in the low "pentium one" type of range.

So hosted web sites are often better (they don't have such draconian CPU throttles). But as more and more web hosting companies switch their hosted server farms to cloud computing systems? Well then we see much lower CPU given to each user.

There is a VAST and SPECTACULAR different between web hosting, and that of using cloud computing hosted web sites. Cloud computing is based around a "utility" model. That means just like you can't run a welding rig from a standard wall plug?
Well, then you go out and buy a truck with a heavy duty generator on the back, and use that for your welding equipment. So cloud computing has significantly less horsepower given to each users.

But just like a company providing electricity to the whole city? They serve far many more users, and do so at lower costs. But that comes with restrictions, such as not letting one household draw too much power to effect others on that street.
So, you are limited more for that convenience and lower cost delivery of power. So you need to use that welding generator on the back of the truck. The power company not going to let you take power that could run the whole block of houses!

If this is the same computer, same memory, and same CPU box for both tests? Then there should not be much difference in runtime.

Then you should not see much difference in speed or available CPU. However, if this is your computer vs grid or utility computing (as opposed to a hosted web site), then all bets are off.

***Edit:***

While the poster has NOT come back and confirmed if the two tests are running on the same computer?

It is possible that the compiler optimizations for the web application are NOT turned on. While network, or database reading don't change much with compiler optimizations turned on? (since MOST of your code time is spent in the .net framework - not the application code.

however, for pure looping and code written in vb.net, or in C# that is not working with networks or database?

In these cases? Turing on compiler optimizations TURNS OUT to increase performance by about a factor of 5 times (especially looping code). And the factor in difference between the two quoted times here are RATHER close to the 4-5 times range.

In other words, there are few coincidences in this computer industry? Given the factor between the two times? And given the compiler optimizations are also known to increase non "supervisor" looping code (time running one's written .net code as opposed to time spent running .net library code)?

Then this is a REALLY good issue to check.

That option is this one:
[image]

And then this option:

[image]

The overflow does not help much in most cases (you not notice much difference in most cases).

However, turn on optimizations for looping intensive code? HUGE increase in performance - in fact about 4-5 times. And wonders of wonders, ***that known and often seen performance increase is about the SAME factor as the posters reported difference between the console application, and the web based one.***